# How do I remove Windows drive letter information

Tags: windows, drive-letter

Windows remembers drive letters for all disks. Where is this information stored and is there a way to delete/reset it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s stored under `HKLM\System\MountedDevices` in the registry. To remove it, run [diskpart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc770877(WS.10).aspx) and then enter:

```
automount scrub
```

Comment: what does this do to C drive letter? or is it protected?

Comment: It deletes only letters for unconnected drives.